# Cannot export/import interfaces in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanted to put my interface/type in a seperate file so I could import it later but for some reason I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/types/settings.ts' does not provide an export named 'default'

Here is my **types/settings.ts**

```
interface Settings {
    activeUserId: number
}

export default Settings
```

And here is how I import it:

```
import Settings from '@/types/settings'
```

Same error shows if I try to export a **Type** but it works fine if I export a Class. I can't understand what I am doing wrong here.

I am using Vue 3/Vite with Typescript.

Comment: You can’t export a type as the module default. It’s metadata. There’s no runtime representation

Answer (score 0):

Don't use default export.

Use the following instead.

```js
// types/settings.ts
export interface Settings {
    activeUserId: number
}
```

```js
import { Settings } from '@/types/settings'
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/types/settings.ts' does not provide an export named 'Settings'

Comment: @MartinZeltin If you are under circumstances, where you should have `isolatedModules` on, you may need `import type { Settings } from ...` or `import { type Settings } from ...`